# can you please provide me the mysql query for below table.i need to get build with success and failure count

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table in mysql.i need to get buildname,methodresult,count of same build  methodresult counts.

**i need to get build with that build success and failure count**

MY table:

```
appName   | buildName | versionName | methodResult
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  sfd     | b1        | v1          | success      
  sfd     | b1        | v2          | success      
  sfd     | b1        | v1          | failure      
  sfd     | b1        | v2          | failure      
  sfd     | b2        | v2          | success      
  sfd     | b2        | v3          | success      
  sfd     | b2        | v3          | failure      
  sfd     | b2        | v2          | failure
```

my result table should look like:

```
buildname | methodResult | count(methodResult)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  b1      | success      |  2          
  b1      | failure      |  2                
  b2      | success      |  2          
  b2      | failure      |  2
```

can you please provide me the query to get above result

Comment: PLZ do some google before putting such kind of ques on SO. this will asves your tme as well as of the expertise also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write somthing like:-

```
SELECT buildname, methodResult, COUNT(methodResult)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY buildname, methodResult;
```

Comment: thank you it worked.i used earler broup by buildname and methodresult.so that did not work.finall you soved my problem.thank you once again